# chilkatdotnet45.dll not found in Windows10 Pro

Tags: chilkat

I've done a VS application which doesn't install onto a Windows 10 Pro laptop due to 'chilkatdotnet45.dll not found, other dependencies not found' etc. although it is there in the correct folder. The laptop already has NET Framework 3.5 installed and also vcredist_x64 for 2013 and 2019 have been installed on the laptop. The problem does NOT occur on my W10 development machine, nor on the customer's previous W10 computer.
Any ideas as to what I can do to overcome the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Chilkat .NET assembly built with VS2012.   (There are two options for the 4.5 Framework.  One is built with VS2012, the other with VS2013.)

See http://cknotes.com/chilkat-net-assemblies-matching-visual-studio-versions-to-net-framework-versions-to-vc-runtime-versions/

Comment: I downloaded and installed the recommended vcredist, in my case the 2015/17/19 version, still the same error message. NET Framework 4 is already installed. Do I need Microsoft .NET Core SDK? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community on the client's computer, which did in fact allow the app to run, whereas installing vcredist_whatever did not. I've told the client not to set up as a software-developer competitor to me, but I'm not sure he heard me.